# Leaflet won't display markers when loaded dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, leaflet

If i link the script myself like this:

```
<script src="dist/js/osm/leaflet.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

everything works fine. But as soon as i want to dynamically load my script like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "dist/js/osm/leaflet.js",
    dataType: "script",
    async: false
});
```

The map will show but all markers which should be displayed wnt show up.
As you can see i also tried

```
async: false
```

but that wont solve the problem.

Note: I also load a second script i wrote myself, but that works perfectly fine when loaded dynamically. The only thing that wont work is to add markers to the shown map, as i mentioned erlier.

Please help me with this,
thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show us more code(how do you create map/markers?)

Comment: @Dr.Molle The function where i add markers to the map works perfectly fine, as well as the rest of the code. I think the problem is that the code which will be loaded dynamically is in another scope as the other code and because the addTo function to add markers to the map wont work in this way...hope thats somehow understandable

Comment: And how do you expect a solution without showing the used code?

Comment: @Dr.Molle i am showing the code needed. If i use the static binding add the script on my own with the script tag everything works. But when i add it dynamically at runtime it fails. What is there more to add?

Comment: Solved it, by simply adding the script with head.appendchild(). Thanks ayway :-)

Answer (score 7):

When you dynamically load leaflet like this it won't be able to work out where it was loaded from, so it won't be able to determine the correct URL for the marker icon. The reason is that it looks for the `script` tag that loaded leaflet to work out what path it was loaded from and when you load using AJAX like this there is no `script` tag for it to find.

You can work around this by setting `L.Icon.Default.imagePath` to the base URL of the leaflet images after leaflet has loaded and before creating any markers.

Comment: @Andreas then you should probably answer your own question and accept that as correct.